# UI Bootstrap ng-repeat elements using the uib-popover with a close button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a list of elements that are shown by an **ng-repeat** and each of them uses the uib-popover directive to show the details of each element.. so the thing I'm trying to figure out is how to add a close button that acts on the current popover element but is actually outside of the **popover-content** as you may see in my example:

[image]

```
<div class="popover-inner">
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right" style="margin-right:6px;margin-top:6px" title="Close" ng-click=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-times"></i></button>
  <h3 class="popover-title ng-binding ng-scope" ng-bind="uibTitle" ng-if="uibTitle">Title</h3>
    <div class="popover-content" uib-tooltip-template-transclude="contentExp()" tooltip-template-transclude-scope="originScope()">
      <!-- MY CUSTOM HTML OUTPUT -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I'm not entirely sure if I can use the **popover-is-open** attribute on this case because I don't know if I have to declare the variable in both scopes  (**the controller that list each parent item and the directive itself to control each popover individually**)

```
<div class="label ng-binding ng-scope label-success" ng-repeat="target in data.target_status" popover-trigger="none" popover-title="Title" uib-popover-template="'./template/custom.html'" popover-is-open="isOpen" popover-append-to-body="false" popover-placement="right">Title</div>
```

By the way the ng-click attribute that is in the button doesn't work I'm not even able to print a "hello world" from it or fire anything

Thanks